# Is it possible to prevent iterator from reaching end of file?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, with-statement

I tried to find an answer to this question, but I guess I can't really pinpoint the source of my problem. If this has been answered elsewhere, I'd appreciate it if you could take a moment to explain what I'm missing.

Basically, I thought you could do something like this:

```
ref = open(ref_file)
with ref:
    for row in ref:
         break

with ref:
    for row in ref:
        print(row)
```

Since I used a `break` statement in the first loop, I thought it'd stop the iterator, put a pause on reading the file, and then I could pick up where I left off with the second loop. This doesn't turn out to be the case- it instead throws me an error saying I am trying to work on a closed file. I reasoned through it, and I came to the conclusion that, perhaps, the `with` statement is what pushes the iterator to EOF. So I tried this:

```
with ref:
    for row in ref:
         break

    for row in ref:
        print(row)
```

This seemed to work as expected. Awesome. So, the next thing I tried is this:

```
with ref:
    for i in range(0,10):
        for row in vcf:
             break

        for row in vcf:
            print(row)
```

What I'd expect to happen here is, essentially, to print alternating rows until the range of `0,10` is exhausted. Instead, I print the second row of the file, and it stops.

Is there a better way to prevent an iterator from reaching EOF? What am I missing? Am I somehow breaking out of the with statement and missing the point?

EDIT:

Okay, the last example isn't exemplary of the issue I'm having.

```
with ref:
    for i in range(0,10):
        for row in vcf:
             break

        for row in vcf:
            print(row)
            break
```

This works as expected... Which really leaves me thinking I'm missing something in my real code. I'd still appreciate commentary on better ways to prevent an iterator from reaching EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation here is incorrect: it reads one line then breaks then reads the rest of the file, 10 times:

```
with ref:
    for i in range(0,10):
        for row in vcf:
             break

        for row in vcf:
            print(row)
```

note that you can iterate manually using `next` instead of breaking out of a `for` loop. More pythonic:

```
for _ in range(10):
    next(vcf,None)

# unindent here
for row in vcf:
    print(row)
```

the `None` argument in `next` ensures that even if the file is shorter than 10 lines, it doesn't raise `StopIteration` but yields a default value (that you're ignoring)

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois; I found my own bug in the example code above shortly after I posted above. I ended up going through my real code and figuring out what the real issue was a few hours later, but what you did post does answer the question above. My issue turned out to be unrelated.

Comment: I posted an answer to show a better way to manually iterate on a file handle (or on anything else). Creating a loop to break it afterwards is a bit clumsy :) `next` is not that well-known, and that's a pity.